# Creating a drop down menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Full disclosure: I feel like this is a really dumb question, but I'm brand new to Drupal and am having quite a time getting something so simple to take place. I'm used to the Wordpress community so finding things on Drupal has been a challenge. Maybe it's a lack of help compared to WP or maybe it's just that I haven't learnt quite how to look for (or where to look for) what I need.

Whatever the case. I've sliced up a designers work and laid it atop Zurb's Foundation. I'm now in the process of placing this over the Bartik theme (feel free to point me in another direction if this is a bad choice..).

Here's how the menus are setup in Baritk, with slight tweaking by me (ie taking the header out):

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
            <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
              'links' => $main_menu,
              'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'main-menu-links',
                'class' => array('main-nav'),
              )
            )); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
        <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          )
        )); ?>
```

I've set the secondary links to read from the Main Menu I've setup which has the main pages and subsequent sub pages. This is the best setup, right?

If so, what's the best Drupal-esque way to merge these two? Is there an easier call, function, etc. besides using both of these separately?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you is probably to use the [nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module.

Comment: I'd seen that elsewhere and so installed it. Problem was that all of the "how to" guides are pointing to areas/menus/contexts that either don't exist in my Drupal install or simply can't find.

Comment: The module should just provide blocks which you manage on the block page. admin/structure/block